# HttpResponse code not 200

Tags: java

i'm running a simple java program to get HttpResponse codes, however for some reason not all codes happen to be 200. I find this odd because when checking the network tab for certain URLs like www.reddit.com, the Response is 200, but my program is returning a different value.

The code below...

```
try{
        String urlName = "http://www.reddit.com";

        URL url = new URL(urlName);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();
        String message = connection.getResponseMessage();
        System.out.println("Message: " + message);
        int code = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println(Integer.toString(code));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Lastly, is there a reason to set the RequestMethod to GET and connection again? I get the response code whether or not I have that code because the connection executes openConnection();

Goal - make all valid connections return 200

Comment: What _is_ it printing, if not 200?

Comment: @MattBall 301 for Reddit, 302 for facebook, however google is returning 200. All should be 200 if you check under the network tab

Comment: That's a redirect. Your browser's following them; your code isn't. I strongly recommend using a better HTTP client library, such as Apache's HttpClient, or [Horizon](https://github.com/HubSpot/horizon) by HubSpot (the company I work for). Java's built-in HTTP support is not great for end-users.

Comment: @MattBall Thanks. I'll test it out with Apache's HttpClient. How should I resolve this question? Should I delete it or could you comment and I mark you down as resolved?

Comment: Happy to post an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said that you're seeing a 301 for Reddit and a 302 for Facebook. [Those status codes mean that you're getting redirected.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) Your browser's following them; your code isn't.

Java's built-in HTTP support is not great for end-users. I strongly recommend using a better HTTP client library, such as [Apache's HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/), or [Horizon](https://github.com/HubSpot/horizon), which is built on top of Apache (for synchronous requests) and Ning (for async).

---

Full disclosure: I work for HubSpot; Horizon is one of our open-source libraries.

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice if you posted the error code it did give...

I ran your code myself and the error was 301, meaning moved permanently.

If you go to http://www.reddit.com yourself, you will see that you get redirected to the httpS version of reddit. Changing this in the urlName will fix your problem.

Edit: same goes for facebook as i saw in comments to your question, google does not require https always so that does work.